# TimeSeries - Seasonal Charting Analysis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, quantitative-finance, stocks

```
  Date       Open   High   Low   Close  Volume
1993-01-29  27.14  27.14  27.00  27.12  1625280
1993-02-01  27.14  27.31  27.14  27.31  778338
1993-02-02  27.29  27.39  27.23  27.37  325941
```

Hi,

I have this timeseries from the S&P500 index (daily data) starting on 1993 all the way to 2018. 
I was trying to build seasonal charts, like the January movement from day 1 to 31 since 1993 in one chart or the evolution of prices from January to December to see the sell in May effect.
Forgot to say that I'm only using the close column.

Thanks...

Steve

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: starting from 1993...